# Haskell interact function

Tags: haskell

I’m new to Haskell and have a problem with `interact` function. This is my sample program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = interact inputLength

inputLength :: String -> String
inputLength input = show $ length input
```

It compiles but when running doesn’t print the output - just prints the string that is passed to it and moves to the next line. When I pass the `interact` another `String -> String` function like this:

```
upperCase :: String -> String
upperCase input = map toUpper input
```

it runs ok and prints the argument in uppercase as expected – so what is wrong with the first function?

Comment: I think `interact` is still a lovely way to write command-line programs that are meant to work with pipes.  With `IO` I am tempted to write non-composable user-only programs.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The  `String -> String` argument given to `interact` should take a string containing *all* the input and return a string containing *all* the output.  The reason you see output after pressing enter with `interact (map toUpper)` is because `map toUpper` acts lazily -- it can start giving output before all the input is known.  Finding the length of a string is not like this -- the whole string must be known before any output can be produced.

You need to either signal an EOF to say that you are done entering input (in the console, this is Control-D on Unix/Mac systems, I believe it's Control-Z on Windows), then it will give you the length.  Or you can find the length of each line by saying so:

```
interact (unlines . map inputLength . lines)
```

This will always be lazy in each line, so you know you can get one output after each input.

Since acting on lines is such a common pattern, I like to define a little helper function:

```
eachLine :: (String -> String) -> (String -> String)
eachLine f = unlines . map f . lines
```

Then you can do:

```
main = interact (eachLine inputLength)
```

Comment: For us newbie, i will add that:  `inputLength = show . length`

Answer (score 3):

A more reusable solution:

```
main = interactLineByLine processLine

-- this wrapper does the boring thing of mapping, unlining etc.... you have to do all the times for user interaction
interactLineByLine:: (String -> String) -> IO ()
interactLineByLine f = interact (unlines . (map processLine) . lines) 

-- this function does the actual work line by line, i.e. what is
-- really desired most of the times
processLine:: String -> String
processLine line = "<" ++ line ++ ">"
```