# interact function waiting non-stop. Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's consider  the function:
    import Data.Char

```
convertStringToInt :: String -> Int
convertStringToInt s = convertStringToInt' s 1 0
    where 
          convertStringToInt'  [] _ res    = res
          convertStringToInt' (h:t) m res = convertStringToInt' t (m*10) (res + (((ord h) - 48)*m))

f :: String -> String 
f s = (show . convertStringToInt)s

main = interact f
```

When I input "1212" it will happen nothing. Just prompt is still waiting.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interact` reads the whole input first, then prints the result of passing the whole input to the function. And unless the working function needs only an initial portion of the input, the Haskell run time needs to read until the end of input. Your function consumes the whole string, so that is what happens.

Hence, you won't get a result until you finish input (i.e. CTRL+D in Unix).

Comment: This is not really true. `interact` prints the result of applying the function to the whole input, but thanks to lazy IO, this does not in general mean that the whole input is read first, before anything is printed. It is true for the particular `f` in this question though because `f` is strict in its entire input string.

Comment: @ReidBarton I'm not so sure that it is demanded to implement `interact` with lazy I/O, or that lazy I/O needs to exist at all. Hence what you describe is an implementation detail of a particular haskell implementation.

Comment: The Haskell Report says "The `getContents` operation returns all user input as a single string, which is read lazily as it is needed", and the specification of `interact` is in terms of `getContents`. (Anyways what particular Haskell implementation did you have in mind that behaves as you described?)

Comment: None in particular, @ReidBarton, but I thought that lazy I/O is a GHC speciality. Looks like I'm wrong.

Comment: @ReidBarton  I hope my edit makes it more correct now. I tried to avoid technical terms like "lazy IO" though.

Comment: It's mostly the words "first, then" that I object to; "and" would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer already at [Haskell interact function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799755/haskell-interact-function). The IO is lazy by default. If you want the function to deal with your input line-by-line what you can do is to use the `unline` function:

`interact (unlines . map (show . length) . lines)`

With a helper function

```
eachLine :: (String -> String) -> (String -> String)
eachLine f = unlines . map f . lines
```

Then you can:

`main = interact (eachLine inputLength)`