# Haskell - How do I break out of interact?

Tags: loops, haskell, input, io, user-input

I am using `interact` to process some user inputs step-by-step (specifically, it's a chess program). However, I haven't found a way to deal with the situation where the user might want to just break out of the loop and start this match of chess from the beginning.

When I'm executing a normal procedure in ghci, pressing `Ctrl-C` will not exit the whole ghci, but will just stop the procedure itself and allow me to go on with some other procedures. However, if I press `Ctrl-C` in the console with the `interact` function in effect, the following message is shown:

```
^CInterrupted.
*Main> 
<stdin>: hGetChar: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

And then I have to launch ghci all over again.

I also thought of catching special user inputs such as "exit", however, since the type of `interact` is `interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()`, the input will have to go through the function typed `(String -> String)` first, and I haven't found a way for that function to notify the main IO that it should quit.

How should I break out of `interact`? Or is `interact` not intended to be used this way and I should compose custom IO functions?

Comment: have you tried <CTRL>-D ?

Comment: @Carsten Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @Carsten The literal character ^D gets shown in the terminal.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @Carsten Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: usually `interact` will work on the input stream till EOF and you should be able to send this using `CTR-D` or `CTR-Z`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827615/interact-function-waiting-non-stop-haskell

Comment: I generally think of `interact` as a blast from the past. It's very rarely seen these days, and I think it's mostly still here for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How should I break out of `interact`?

You can't. You can think of `interact f` as `getContents >>= putStrLn . f`. And `getContents` will close the handle on `stdin`. Any further operation concerning reading will fail.

> The literal character ^D gets shown in the terminal

That's a problem with readline. GHCi changes the buffering method of `stdin` from `LineBuffer` to `NoBuffering` to use readline optimally. If you want to exit `interact` with `^D`, you need to change the buffering method:

```
ghci> import System.IO
ghci> hGetBuffering stdin
NoBuffering
ghci> hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
ghci> interact id
hello world
hello world
pressing control-D after the next RETURN
pressing control-D after the next RETURN
<stdin>: hGetBuffering: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

> Or is `interact` not intended to be used this way and I should compose custom `IO` functions?

Yes, it's not intended to be used this way. `interact` is meant to use all input and dictate all output. If you want to use use line-wise input, you can write your own line-wise interact method (or use an external library):

```
import Control.Monad (when)

interactLine :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
interactLine f = loop
  where
    loop = do
      l <- getLine
      when (l /= "quit") $ putStrLn (f l) >> loop
```

Comment: I think this name `interact` is a bit misleading though. Normally when you think of "interacting" you'd think of something more complicated than what this function provides.

Comment: @JIXiang: It's more or less interacting as something in a command line pipe, e.g. `program1 | haskellprogram | program3`. It's not really meant for human input, though, that's true.

Comment: @EPo no, that's from `Control.Monad`.