# Understanding Haskell's Laziness

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I was reading: [Haskell interact function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799755/haskell-interact-function)

So I tried

```
interact (unlines . map (show . length) . lines)
```

And it worked as I expected. I type something, press enter, then I get the length printed at the prompt.

So then I wanted to try make it simply repeat what I typed, so I tried

```
interact (unlines . map id . lines)
```

But now it repeats every character I type in. Why is that? I thought the trick was in the `lines` followed by `unlines` - but it's clearly not. `lines "a"` produces `["a"]`, so how come in the first function when I start typing my input, it doesn't just immediately give "1" as the output? There's clearly something I misunderstand about "Finding the length of a string is not like this -- the whole string must be known before any output can be produced."

Comment: Additionally, how could I rewrite my "echo" program so that it only repeats what was given __after__ pressing enter?

Comment: Because at that point the `lines` is still "blocking" on the first line.

Comment: It's worth noting that `unlines . map id . lines = id`.

Comment: Lists in Haskell are linked lists, and due to Haskell's laziness, these are not (per) se fully evaluated. You can see the input channel as a linked list, where it is "blocking" on the characters you still need to enter. `lines` processes the stream and when a new line is reached, it starts a new element in the list. Since `length` can only calculate the length of an entire list, `length` thus will wait, but `id` does not, since for `id` since it just returns the list under construction, and that string is each time extended when you enter a character.

Comment: Ah, trying `interact (show . lines)` is making it a bit clearer, I can see it keeps on adding stuff inside the `[...` and it never gets to `]'.

Comment: I'm still curious how I can get the "echo" behaviour using the `interact` function. Or would this be considered misuse?

Comment: @CameronBall: you can use `seq` (and derived functions like `seqList` to force evaluation) https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-8.6.5/docs/Util.html#v:seqList

Comment: But in general the idea is to be as lazy as possible, since this makes it sometimes possible to process infinite lists. As in you can define an infinite list of prime numbers, filter on the numbers that contain at least four digits, and then take the first 26 numbers.

Comment: Why would it immediately give you "1" as output? After all, the length of the line might start with a 2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that `lines "a"` produces `["a"]` does not mean that if you are currently entering `a`, that `lines` just processes the input to a list `["a"]`. You should see the input as a (possibly) infinite list of characters. In case the prompt is waiting for user input, it is thus "blocking" on the next input.

That however does *not* mean that functions like `lines` can *not* partially resolve the result already. `lines` has been implemented in a lazy manner such that it processes the stream of characters, and each time when it sees a new line character, it starts emitting the next element. This thus means that `lines` could process an infinite sequence of characters into an infinite list of lines.

If you use [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) however, then this requires the list to be evaluated (not the *elements* of the list however). So that means `length` will only emit an answer from the moment `lines` starts emitting the next item.

You can use `seq` (and variants) to force the evaluation of a term before a certain action is done. For example [**`seq :: a -> b -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq) will evaluate the first parameter to *Weak Head Normal Form (WHNF)*, and then return the second parameter.

Based on `seq`, other functions have been constructed, like [**`seqList :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists-0.4.2/docs/Data-Lists.html) in the [**`Data.Lists`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists-0.4.2/docs/Data-Lists.html#seqList) of the [**`lists`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lists) package.

We can use this to postpone evaluation until the first line is known, like:

```
-- will echo full lines

import Data.Lists(seqList)

interact (unlines . map (\x -> seqList x x) . lines)
```

Comment: Great answer. I think I was fixating on it a bit because to me `interact` implied user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

This is to do with lazy evaluation. I'll try to explain this in as intuitive a way as possible.

When you write `interact (unlines . map (show . length) . lines)`, every time a character is input, we don't actually know what the next output character can be until you press enter. So, you get the behaviour you expected.

However, at every point in `interact (unlines . map id . lines) = interact id`, every time you enter a character, it's guaranteed that that character is included in the output. So, if you input a character, that character is also output immediately.

This is one of the reasons that the word "lazy" is a bit of a misnomer. It's true that Haskell will only evaluate something when it needs to, but the flipside of that is that when it needs to, it'll do so as soon as possible. Here Haskell needs to evaluate the output since you want to print it, so it evaluates it as much as it can—one character at a time—ironically making it seem eager!

More specifically, `interact` isn't intended for real time user input—it's intended for file input, in which you pipe a file into an executable with bash. It should be run something like this:

```
$ runhaskell Interactor.hs < my_big_file.txt > list_of_lengths.txt
```

If you want line-by-line buffering, you'll probably have to do it manually, unless you want to 'trick' the compiler as Willem does. Here's some very simple code that works as you expect—but note that it has no exit state unlike `interact`, which will terminate at the EOF.

```
main = do
  ln <- getLine -- Buffers until you press enter
  putStrLn ln   -- Print the line we just got
  main          -- Loop forever
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment on `interact`'s intended usage. I felt as though it was designed for user interaction, but it seems not to be the case.